# Were these two actors in Bullet Train filmed separately?

Tags: production, bullet-train

I was watching [Bullet Train](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt12593682/) and I noticed something very odd in the final scenes.

Spoilers ahead.

In the final scenes where Brad Pitt and Sandra Bullock something seemed off to me... Like they were filmed separately and composed together in post production. The light looks different on their faces, and when they look at each other it seems they're gaze is not aligned. There are one or two physical interactions between them (which could've been done with a stand-in and just replaced Bullock's face digitally) but for the rest  of the shots I started thinking if perhaps she was filmed separately due to whatever reasons (conflicting schedule perhaps).

I have seen an interview in [Entertainment Weekly](https://ew.com/movies/bullet-train-surprise-cameos-brad-pitt-sandra-bullock/) where Pitt talks about having Bullock cameo in this movie while he would appear in hers, and there is an article on [People](https://people.com/movies/bullet-train-sandra-bullock-brad-pitt-set-photos/) with photos of them on the set... But that doesn't mean she was there *for all the scenes*.

Is there any evidence that points to Sandra Bullock not being on set together for all the scenes with Brad Pitt or is what I saw just the result of weird lighting / digital effects / something else?

Comment: I've no hard evidence either way. It's definitely 'windier' when we're seeing Pitt over Bullock's shoulder than the reverse shot. The entirety of that scene is very probably shot indoors against bluescreen, so that's an art department error. Lighting will be re-mapped for every shot under those conditions, so there are no clues in that. That partial scene *could* have been shot in a day; which wouldn't preclude them managing to find a day they could both make it. Nothing to me says the reverse in each case is a stand-in/double, though it equally could be.

Comment: Of course, the fact there's wind affecting both actor's hair - though two versions of 'wind' would be a tough one for CGI to match, twice, which lends further credence to them both being there at all times [still may be a double].

Answer (score -1):

well, it could be the weird lighting or several things why, these two actors look weird or funny looking in a movie. Most actors who have a small, cameo, or very little to no part in the movie, usually don't stay or be present for the making of most of the movie. A lot of actors don't like to be present on a movie set or a show set unless they have to be there. Usually, actors will stay in their dressing room or trailer, til it's time for them to go on set. Once their part is done, they go back to their dressing room or trailer.

Comment: I know she wouldn't be there _for the whole movie_ but I was wondering if she filmed the scenes with Brad Pitt _at the same time_ he was there.

Comment: This is a bit simplistic overall & doesn't go near answering the question.